# MS Unit tests fails run half of the time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I got this odd behaviour I launch tests from MS Test List Editor.

And first time I launch I always get this error currently

> Error 11/15/2011 4:28:32 PM   Failed to queue test run 'USER@MACHINE 2011-11-15
>   15:28:29': Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe'.

Next launch is fine

I reproduced it 40 times already. Just as if first launch is clearing way for second one.

What could be the cause?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536475/launching-unit-tests-in-debugger-fails-every-other-time-cannot-start-qtagent32-exe

Comment: right, so microsoft is in denial..

Comment: Denial is a large river in Africa.  They need a repro, you could perhaps provide them with one?  Look through the workaround tab for possible solutions.

Comment: Its working for me now, after VS restart. Hans thanks for the link. I just thought issue is going to be more serious hence thread. Also I searched for solution first, but then after question was ready I didn't search for it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans pointed out its a known issue.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536475/launching-unit-tests-in-debugger-fails-every-other-time-cannot-start-qtagent32-exe

Its hard to reproduce and in my case I was able to fix it by reloading VS 2010.